# Error running fully_connected_feed.py

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

When I run the fully_connected_feed.py code:

```
     https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py", line 277, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 43, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py", line 222, in main
run_training()
  File "C:/Users/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py", line 120, in run_training
data_sets = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.input_data_dir, FLAGS.fake_data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\mnist.py", line 211, in read_data_sets
SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\datasets\base.py", line 142, in maybe_download
gfile.Copy(temp_file_name, filepath)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 316, in copy
compat.as_bytes(oldpath), compat.as_bytes(newpath), overwrite, status)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: Read fewer bytes than requested
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Given that Alex got this working on another system, my first suspicion falls on your data files.  Are you sure they haven't been corrupted in some way?  Looking at the specific error, maybe something else is updating your files as you copy them?

Comment: Alex is using Mac, Im trying to set this up on Windows.

Comment: True, but the fact that he got it working shows that it's not something wrong with tensorflow as such.  It's either the glue for Windows or your environment.  Looking at the error (that says it cannot read all the bytes from the file), I strongly suspect your environment...

Answer (score 2):

After doing the following, I was able to run the script without errors. The key for getting it to work for me, was the version of tensorflow installed has to match the tutorial code, otherwise there were exceptions. Although, I got a different exception than you, at first.

After installing tensorflow, check version. Details of this step may be different if you installed it pip or some other method:

```
$ conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /Users/agr/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow:
#
tensorflow                0.11.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
```

Clone the git repo

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Inspect the tags available and checkout the release matching your install:

```
$ cd tensorflow
$ git tag -l -n1
...
$ git checkout v0.11.0
```

Run script!

```
$ cd examples/tutorials/mnist/ 
$ python fully_connected_feed.py
```

The key point being, run the script from here, not from the link you posted in the original question.

Comment: Tensorflow Version: 0.12.0-rc0

Comment: OK, did you try what I suggested? i.e. do `git checkout 0.12.0-rc0` so you are running the version of the script that is found in the repository under that release tag.

Comment: There are differences between the script in the master branch and the 0.12.0-rc0 release. I dont know if it is what is causing your error, but it is something to rule out in the troubleshooting process:

Comment: Here is the version of the script which should work with your tensorflow version:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/0.12.0-rc0/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py

Comment: I reran using the new script and I got the same error.

Comment: Darn! Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately I don't have windows to test on. I gave it a good go, though.

Comment: Maybe try installing tensorflow via conda, which is what I did. It is a matter of preference but I find conda does very well with the more complex scientific packages.

Comment: I used Anaconda3 to install it

Comment: For what it is worth, I was able to run it using v0.11.0 on OS X using conda.

Answer (score 2):

### TL; DR

Something else is altering your files as you create them.  Find the process and stop it.

### Research

I've just run the demo with Windows 10, Python 3.5, tensorflow 0.12.0 with no errors.  It is therefore something about your environment.

Looking at the actual [line of the error](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0a4676ed1fcdc5a7c4122d5feb21e37372eb5f75/tensorflow/core/platform/windows/windows_file_system.cc#L122), you are failing to read the required number of bytes from the open file.  Going further up the stack you can see that CopyFile is actually trying to read all the bytes of a file into a string in [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dd01113c2b9efb16c3c3ea0a4aaa340a0494696f/tensorflow/core/platform/env.cc#L204).  This starts by finding out the current file size and then trying to read all the bytes.

The problem is that the file size at the start of this process doesn't match the size by the end of the copy.  In other words, something else has altered your file.

## What next?

Your best bet is to try to find out what else is accessing your file.  I suggest you use the techniques explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/521476/detect-what-process-is-changing-a-file-on-windows) to see what else has the file open as you are running the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on Windows 2012 Server.

As suggested in the previous post, I downloaded and launched Process Monitor, then set the filter: "Path contains mnist" [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnEIv.png). The datasets were  downloaded and unpacked correctly, while running code both from Spyder and  Jupyter.

I suspect that there is a race condition in the library code, i.e. missing synchronization between downloading and unpacking operations. As Process Monitor introduced additional delays, the datasets were sucessfully downloaded before the next operation started, hence the hazardous behavior was not observed.